# Circular dll dependency in WPF application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, circular-dependency

I have 3 projects. Say Project Lib1, Lib2, UI. Of these, UI is the WPF UI project. The UI project references Lib1, and project Lib2 also references Lib1.

Now I have a situation when I want to reference Lib2 in UI project, and I am getting a circular dependency.

Can someone please tell me how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: This should not cause a Circular dependency. I think you are missing something. In this case a CD can only be caused if Lib1 references Lib2 or UI.

Comment: Yes I agree with Yogesh that is not a circular reference. You must be missing something. A build order of Lib1, Lib2, UI will compile in the scenario you decribe. But ... I think I have seen VS giving such an error when the real problem was something like I had a .Net 4 client profile dll referencing a .Net 4 dll. Just check your dll targets are all the same.

Comment: It was my bad. I had a wrong reference that was causing the circular dependency. Thanks for your help.